# Azure core bot Luis integration gives error on running via emulator: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Resource Not Found'

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

Steps I followed:

1.created a Bot service using core bot template **https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/releases/download/Templates/core.zip** through cookiecutter.

2.created LUIS app on LUIS.ai and added the configurations for the same in **config.py** file.

Now, when i try running the bot locally from emulator, i am getting error:**Operation returned an invalid status code 'Resource Not Found'**

I am entirely new to Bot framework.Sorry if i missed any detail.

Comment: Have you looked at the Python Core-Bot sample? https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/13.core-bot

Comment: I haven't tested the core.zip in the python repo, but I know for a fact (having tested last week) that the sample one works.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes yes, i tried running the Core-Bot sample. I followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp to add LUIS to the bot service.

Comment: can you try a raw query from your browser like this: https://<REGION>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/<LUISAPPID>?subscription-key=<LUISAPIKEY>&q='<QUERY>'

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I tried querying endpoint directly and that's working fine for me.